# How to put characters from file into two-dimensional vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, 2d-vector

I've been trying to read in characters from an external file to be put into a two-dimensional vector with type `char`. The elements must be able to be compared to certain values in order to navigate a maze given in "`MazeSample.txt`".

While I haven't been able to get characters be put into the vector, I was able to read and output the characters with the `get` and `cout` functions.
The following code is an attempt to read the vectors in the correct format, but provides an error in the end:

```
//MazeSample.txt
SWWOW
OOOOW
WWWOW
WEOOW

//source.cpp
vector<vector<char>> maze;
ifstream mazeFile;
char token;

mazeFile.open("MazeSample.txt");

while (!mazeFile.eof()) {
    mazeFile.get(token); //reads a single character, goes to next char after loop

    for (int row = 0; row < maze.size(); row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < maze.at(row).size(); row++) {
            maze.push_back(token);
        }
    }

    //cout << token;
}

mazeFile.close();
```

For the maze provided in "`MazeSample.txt`", I'd expect the `maze` vector to read each character row by row, mimicking the format of the maze sample.

In the above code, am provided with an error at `maze.push_back(token)`:
    "no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back..." matches the argument list"
    "argument types are: (char)"
    "object type is: std::vector>, std::allocator>>>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that you try to put a char into a std::vector of std vector. So you put a wrong type.

`maze.at(row).push_back(token);` would do it, but then no row exists. You also need to push_back and empty row, before you can write data to it.

That is your syntax error.

Then, your code could be drastically shortened by using C++ algorithms. See:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>


std::istringstream testDataFile(
R"#(00000
11111
22222
33333
44444
)#");



// This is a proxy to read a complete line with the extractor operator
struct CompleteLineAsVectorOfChar {
    // Overloaded Extractor Operator
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CompleteLineAsVectorOfChar& cl) {
        std::string s{}; cl.completeLine.clear();  std::getline(is, s); 
        std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(cl.completeLine));
        return is; }

    operator std::vector<char>() const { return completeLine; }  // Type cast operator for expected value
    std::vector<char> completeLine{};
};


int main()
{
    // Read complete source file into maze, by simply defining the variable and using the range constructor
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> maze { std::istream_iterator<CompleteLineAsVectorOfChar>(testDataFile), std::istream_iterator<CompleteLineAsVectorOfChar>() };

    // Debug output:  Copy all data to std::cout
    std::for_each(maze.begin(), maze.end(), [](const std::vector<char> & l) {std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; });

    return 0;
}
```

But this is not the end. A `std::vector<char>`has no advantage over a string. You can work nearly have all the same functionality as a `std::vector<char>`. That is an improvement in design. The code would then look more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream testDataFile(
R"#(00000
11111
22222
33333
44444
)#");

int main()
{
    // Read complete source file into maze, by simply defining the variable and using the range constructor
    std::vector<std::string> maze{ std::istream_iterator<std::string>(testDataFile), std::istream_iterator<std::string>() };

    // Debug output:  Copy all data to std::cout
    std::copy(maze.begin(), maze.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

This is the by far more simpler solution. And it will serve your needs as well.

Please note: I used a istringstream for reading data, becuase I do not have a file on SO. But it is of cause the same as using any other stream (like an ifstream).

**EDIT**

The first solution read the source and put it directly into a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`:

The 2nd solution put everything in the a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` which is the most efficient solution. Also a `std::string` is nearly a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`.

The OP requested a 3rd solution where we use the 2nd solution and then copy the `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` into a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`.

Please see below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream testDataFile(
    R"#(00000
11111
22222
33333
44444
)#");

int main()
{
    // Read complete source file into maze, by simply defining the variable and using the range constructor
    std::vector<std::string> maze{ std::istream_iterator<std::string>(testDataFile), std::istream_iterator<std::string>() };

    // Debug output:  Copy all data to std::cout
    std::copy(maze.begin(), maze.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));


    // Edit: Copy into a std::vector<std::vector<char> -------------------------------------------------------
    std::cout << "\n\n\nSolution 3:\n\n";

    // Define the new variable with number of lines from the first maze
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> mazeChar(maze.size());

    // Copy the data from the original maze
    std::transform(
        maze.begin(),               // Source
        maze.end(), 
        mazeChar.begin(),           // Destination
        [](const std::string & s) {
            std::vector<char>vc;    // Copy columns
            std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(vc)); 
            return vc; 
        }
    );

    // Debug Output
    std::for_each(
        mazeChar.begin(),
        mazeChar.end(),
        [](const std::vector<char> & vc) {
            std::copy(vc.begin(), vc.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps . . .

Comment: Thanks! While the second solution works, is comprehensible, and efficient, how would I be able to insert the characters into a 2D char vector (as per the original question)?

Comment: I added an additional example. But believe me. The 2nd is the best. Maybe you should explain to your instructor that a std::string is nearly the same as a std::vector<char> . . .

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting `char` to `vector<vector<char>>`. You should create a `vector<char>`, insert the values of type `char` into that and then insert the `vector<char>` to `vector<vector<char>> maze;`. Here is the corrected version of your program. It can be written in simple ways but for your understanding, I have made made corrections on top of your program.

```
vector<vector<char>> maze;
ifstream mazeFile;
string token;

mazeFile.open("MazeSample.txt");

while (!mazeFile.eof()) {
    std::getline(mazeFile, token); //reads an entire line

    //Copy characters in entire row to vector of char
    vector<char> vecRow;
    vecRow.assign(token.begin(), token.end());

    //Push entire row of characters in a vector
    maze.push_back(vecRow);

}

mazeFile.close();
```